# How to use gradient in react native

Tags: react-native, expo

Hey guys can anyone tell me how to use gradient in react native without using Linear gradient as i am unable to use it react native bottom tab bar and react native element card.

```
const MainScreen = createBottomTabNavigator(
      {
        Home : {
          screen : HomeStack,
          navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel:"MY MOVIES",
            tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
              <Ionicons
                  name={focused ? 'ios-home' : 'md-home'}
                  size={35}
                  style={{ color: focused ? '#33A3F4' : '#949494'}}
              />
          ),
          }
        },
        AddMovie : {screen : AddMovie,
          navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel:"ADD MOVIE",
            tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
              <Ionicons
                  name={"md-add-circle"}
                  size={focused?35:30}
                  style={{ color: focused ? '#33A3F4' : '#949494'}}
              />

           ), 
          }
        },
      },
      {
        tabBarOptions: {
          activeTintColor: 'tomato',
          inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
          style: {
            backgroundColor:  '#f1f7ed', //want this thing to be gradient
            height:50,
          },
        },
        lazy: true,
        swipeEnabled: true,
        animationEnabled: true,
      }
      );
```

want to change MainScreen(BottontabBar) background to gradient background

Comment: You are creating project using expo???

Comment: yes i am using expo

Comment: Expo by default provided linear gradient. You can check this. https://snack.expo.io/@vishal7008/grad. If it is worked then i will post it as a answer

Comment: it will work but i don't want to use LinearGradient as it only works in component rendering. I want to gradient my bottomTabBarNavigation (of react-navigation).

Comment: I added answer, please check

Answer (score 0):

**Bottom tab bar**

You can use custom component instead of `tabBarComponent` and apply linear gradient there.

**React Native Element Card**

I would try setting padding as 0 and adding LinearGradient as a child element.

```
<Card containerStyle={{padding: 0}}>
  <LinearGradient
    colors={['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']}
  >
    ...
  </LinearGradient>
</Card>
```

Comment: Is there any method to use gradient in the style elements just like css.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible at the moment

Comment: then how i change  react navigation bottomTabBar  color to gradient

Comment: Please go through this tutorial: https://dev.to/hrastnik/lets-create-a-custom-animated-tab-bar-with-react-native-3496. It shows how to create a custom Tab Bar. Then, you render it the very same way as in the example with RN Element Card.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. It may help to solve your problem You can add custom tab into bottomTabNavigator.

```
 const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeStack
    },
    Events: {
      screen: EventStack
    },
    Templates: {
      screen: TemplateStack
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: theme.palette.primaryColor
    },
    tabBarComponent: CustomTab,
    tabBarPosition: "bottom"
  }
);
```

This is my custom tab UI

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react'
import {View, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native'
import I18N from "react-native-i18n";
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import theme from '../theme'
import {Icon} from './Icon'

class CustomTab extends PureComponent {

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      routeNameSelected:'Home'
    }
  }

  getIconName(routeName){
    switch (routeName) {
      case 'First':
        return 'information-outline'
      case 'Second':
        return 'play-box-outline'
      case 'Third':
        return 'comment-text-outline'

    }
  }

  onPressTab(routeName){
    this.props.jumpTo(routeName)
    this.setState({
      routeNameSelected:routeName
    })
  }

  render() {
    const {navigation} = this.props;
    const {routes} = navigation.state;
    return (
        <View style={styles.tabbar}>

        {/*here you can use Linear gradient*/}
          {routes && routes.map((route, index) => {
            return (
              <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                key={route.key}
                style={styles.tab}
                onPress={() => this.onPressTab(route.routeName)}
              >

                <View style={{minHeight:50, justifyContent:'center'}}>
                  {navigation.state.index===index &&
                  <Animatable.View animation="rubberBand" duration={1000} style={styles.tab}>
                    <Icon size={24} name={this.getIconName(route.routeName)} style={{ color: theme.palette.primaryColor }} />
                    <Text style={[styles.tabText,{color: theme.palette.primaryColor}]}>{I18N.t('tabs.'+route.routeName)}</Text>
                  </Animatable.View>
                  }
                  {navigation.state.index!==index &&
                  <View style={styles.tab}>
                    <Icon size={24} name={this.getIconName(route.routeName)} style={{ color: theme.palette.colors.titleColor }} />
                    <Text style={[styles.tabText,{color: theme.palette.colors.titleColor}]}>{I18N.t('tabs.'+route.routeName)}</Text>
                  </View>
                  }
                </View>
              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            );
          })}

        </View>
    )
  }
}

export {CustomTab}
```

Define a state for underlying tab and the view rendered according to this state on CustomTab component.

Please check these link for more understanding

https://dev.to/hrastnik/lets-create-a-custom-animated-tab-bar-with-react-native-3496

https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-a-custom-header-and-custom-bottom-tab-bar-for-react-native-with-react-navigation-969a5d3cabb1